# input box and button aren't matching up IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, button, input, cross-browser

I have a search box on-top of the page I am making, I have been trying to make the page cross-browser friendly as well as have a flexible page resolution.

I have come across this problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T81F6.jpg

The button and the input box don't line up horizontally. No matter what I change it to one is always different than the other on the other browser.

Does anyone know of a cross-browser friendly solution?

html

```
<div id='search'>
                <form>
                    <input class='search' type="text" placeholder="what would you like to find?" required>
                    <input class='button' type="button" value="search">
                </form>
            </div>
```

css

```
#search {
    padding-left:200px;
    margin-right:5px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    }

.search {
    margin-top:5px;
    padding:4px 15px;
    width:250px;
    background:#FFF;
    border:none;
    color:#232d38;
    }

.button {
    position:relative;
    padding:4px 15px;
    left:-4px;
    border:none;
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#232d38;
    }

.button:hover  {
    border:none;
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#000;
    }
```

Comment: Firefox does not play nice with line-height on inputs (of any kind).

Comment: Scratch that! Apparently they decided to implement that in the latest build. Just add font-size:12px to each input.

Comment: Didn't work. On the plus side, smaller font does look nicer.

Comment: @JohnDoe It seems <input> tag is taking 15.33= 16px height in IE compared to firefox's 18px. That is where the problem comes. You can go for <button> tag instead of input.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

The problem is down to the browser’s default styles. Mozilla, in their infinite wisdom, have chosen to put this line in their CSS:

```
button, input[type="reset"], input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] {
line-height:normal !important;
}
```

In Firefox, buttons get an extra 2px padding. In all other browsers they don't. So it is impossible to make them match using just padding.

You have to set top and bottom padding to 0px, and use  `height: 25px; vertical-align: middle;` to make up for the loss of padding.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue, and used John's answer above to come up with a solution without having to use the height and vertical-align properties.

In my reset styling I basically made it so that all inputs had normal line height so that Chrome would render the same as Firefox and IE. The important addition between this and John's code above as targeting the general input selector:

```
button, input[type="reset"], input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input 
{
line-height:normal !important;
}
```